# Enable Android device to access IIS Express whilst on same network

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mobile, localhost, iis-express, android-browser

I am looking for a way to easily test the mobile version of my site in development.

I have set up IIS Express, such that I can access locally using:

http://localhost:1025/AppName/

or by using my PC name (dazbradbury-pc)

http://dazbradbury-pc/AppName/

This then works from any machine on my network.

However, when I try to use this address from an android device, it simply doesn't work. Has anyone got this working? If so, what further steps were required?

Comment: That's probably because Android doesn't do WINS name resolution.  Try the IP address.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks, that was the clue I needed! I've posted an answer for now, but you deserve the credit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @SLaks for the information:

> That's probably because Android doesn't do WINS name resolution. Try
>   the IP address.

Hence, I updated my IIS Express to point to an IP address by inserting into the bindings in `applicationhost.config` an IP address:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:192.168.1.97" />
```

where `192.168.1.97` is the local IP address of my machine.

I can now access my machines IIS Express instance from my android device.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem and almost had the solution... except I was trying to bind with my public IP address so it didn't work.

Comment: If you get Access Denied, **Run Visual Studio as Admin**.

Comment: @nVentimiglia, thank you so much for suggesting running as admin. Totally solved my problem!